# what is typical way to improve model precision/recall for text classification

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, text-mining

I am working on a data mining project that try to auto classify text into t category.
it is a multi-class supervised learning, the input feature include title and body (both are text).
Current accuracy rate is not good, could you please advise some method to improve accuracy?

here is something i have already tried.

1. Pre-processing: Term (could you please suggest a method to extract
   term automatically)
2. Stopword removal (could you please suggest some stop
   word set for English)
3. Stemming
4. Lemmatization
5. N-gram
6. Feature Selection (Information Gain Ratio)

Algorithms: GBDT, LR, SVM and others.

Comment: How are you representing the features? Are the features the terms? How much approximately do you have?

Comment: yes, features are terms, i have tried map word into a vector with mixed ngram, for instance, the sentence "a b c" will generate vector (a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc) and for weight i have tried "bit" "TF" and ”TFIDF"， bit get the better result.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools you can use in order to extract sensible linguistically-grounded feature types. It depends on what is your favourite programming language/environment and if you want to use a machine learning suite which has some text mining components in it, or a text mining component only.

Have a look at:

- Java: [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY29uC4uem8) about text classification), [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)
- Python: [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) and NLTK.

About the stopword lists:

- http://jmlr.org/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a11-smart-stop-list/english.stop
- http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords
- http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.txt
- http://norm.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/
- http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stop.txt